# Send a lot of data from Android device to a server

Tags: php, android, json, httprequest

I need to send a lot of data from my csv in my Android device to a webpage on my server for building a lot of SQL query on my php.

A lot of people speak about using JSON for android, and others people about sending an array of array of array of string by using something like this :

```
String dataPOST = URLEncoder.encode("table") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(tableName) + "&"     + URLEncoder.encode("data") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(sb.toString())+ "&" + URLEncoder.encode("idvente") + "="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(idvente);

        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write(dataPOST);
        wr.flush();
```

But I fear for the limitation of php/my server cause it can be a lot data.
What is the best solution for my problem ?

Thank you and sorry for the mistakes in english, I'm not fluent xD !

Comment: If you're afraid of your server causing issues then you could send the data in chunks?

Comment: nope, it's important for me to send all the data in one chunks cause I have to work with all the data on the php, I have to retrieve the lastId send on the DataBase ,with this id I have to update many others lines in my others data.

But can I send the data in many chunks without erase previous data on my php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make POST request using `MultipartEntity`. You can put any string and files to request body:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

try {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(YOUR_URL);

    MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    multipartEntity.addPart("param1", new StringBody("param1 value", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    multipartEntity.addPart("param2", new StringBody("param2 value", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    if (imagePath.length() > 0) {
        multipartEntity.addPart("images", new FileBody(new File(imagePath)));
    }

    httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

    String resp = httpClient.execute(httpPost, new BasicResponseHandler());
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Also You can try `UrlEncodedFormEntity`. It also has not restrictions of string length.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(sb.toString());

List<NameValuePair> entityParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
entityParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "postcomment"));
entityParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("app_id", com.appbuilder.sdk.android.Statics.appId));
entityParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", com.appbuilder.sdk.android.Statics.appToken));
entityParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("module_id", Statics.MODULE_ID));
entityParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parent_id", pVideoItem.getId() + ""));

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(entityParams, "utf-8"));

String resp = httpClient.execute(httpPost, new BasicResponseHandler());
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this , can you explain why use this :

`if (imagePath.length() > 0) {
        multipartEntity.addPart("images", new FileBody(new File(imagePath)));
    }`

Comment: It has not restrictions of the sting length. It provides a way to send files.

Comment: if (imagePath.length() > 0) {         multipartEntity.addPart("images", new FileBody(new File(imagePath)));     } - it's just eample to attach files

Comment: ok, i'm working on the second one cause I have to download and import MIME4 for the first one , I will writing my feedback soon.

Comment: so i think it work well for me , but I have a lot of harder things to do with that, but I think that it's OK. Thanks you